# Custom return for javascript object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an object based on URL native Object : CustomURL.

I want CustomURL work like "window.location" :

- new CustomURL() return full url in string format (WITHOUT USE OF EXPLICIT toString)
- new CustomURL().host return host

  ```
  class CustomURL extends URL{

    constructor(url,baseurl){
      super(url,baseurl);
    }

    //CUSTOM METHOD
    foo(){

    }
  }
  ```

How can i know if a property is called or not ?

Thanks

Comment: `get host() { ... }` should do it.

Comment: get host () is defined on URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location` does not behave are you describe.

```js
const l = window.location;
console.log(typeof l);
```

It is not a string.

However, if you use it in a context where it is treated as a string, then it will be converted.

This is done by the use of [a `toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

```js
const example = {};

example.toString = function () {
    return "Hello, world";
};

console.log(typeof example);
console.log("Hello? " + example);
```